# Can't do mysql insert on ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I recently uploaded my site from my pc to ubuntu with ssh.
Before I uploaded it worked fine with xampp.
Now everything else is working but mysql insert query.
Connect is working and mysql update. Nothing in mysql `error.log`.

Select is working too.

This is not working

```
$user_query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (id, userid, name) VALUES (:id, :userid, :name)");
if($url_query->execute(array(":id" => "", ":userid" => $userid, ":name" => $name))){
    header("location: /");
}
```

This is working

```
$user_query = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET name=:name WHERE userid =:userid");
if($user_query->execute(array(":name" => $name, ":userid" => $userid))){
    header("location: /");
}
```

I don't see any difference between these two querys.

Table

```
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userid   | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name     | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My host is from digitalocean and I used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) when I installed my apache and mysql

```
$user_query = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE userid=:userid");
    if($user_query->execute(array(":userid" => $userid))){
        if($user_query->rowCount()){

            $user_query = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET name=:name WHERE userid =:userid");
            if($user_query->execute(array(":name" => $name, ":userid" => $userid))){
                header("location: /");
            }

        } else {

            $user_query= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (id, userid, name) VALUES (:id, :userid, :name)");
            if($user_query->execute(array(":id" => "", ":userid" => $userid, ":name" => $name))){
                header("location: /");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check for errors, not in error.log but mysql errors (if PDO - `errorInfo()`, if `mysqli` - `error` property)

Comment: Could it be your user ID already exists in the database when you do your insert?

Comment: I have if statement to check if the row already exist

Comment: Since the `id`-field is set to `auto_increment `, remove it from your insert statement. MySQL will handle that for you. In your current query, you're actually trying to set the `id`-field to an empty string (which _should_ result in an error, since it's a non nullable, unique primary key set as integer and to auto increment).

Comment: I tried without prepare too and didn't work

Comment: Have you tried just removing the `id`-field from your insert query, all together and just have `userid` and `name` in your column, values and execute statement?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes. Thank you. It work now. Post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `id`-field is set to `auto_increment`, remove it from your insert statement. MySQL will handle that for you. In your current query, you're actually trying to set the id-field to an empty string (which should result in an error, since it's a non nullable, unique primary key set as an auto incremented integer).

Try:

```
$user_query= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (userid, name) VALUES (:userid, :name)");
if($user_query->execute(array(":userid" => $userid, ":name" => $name))){
    header("location: /");
}
```

If you get it to work on one server and not another, it might depend on the MySQL version. Newer MySQL-versions are much more picky about the integrity of the values.